# How can I search all file names for all packages in a given repository on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, package-management, rpm

Is there a way to search file names (not contents of files) for packages in a Fedora repository? This would be similar to `rpm -ql [package] | grep term` for every package in the repo, except it would be best to be able to issue the command without the package installed because I want to search through several thousand package file lists. The question I'm trying to answer is:

> Which packages in repository X ship file Y?

The name should suffice because I don't need an exact hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `dnf`:

```
dnf repoquery --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=X -f Y
```

With `yum`:

```
yum -y install yum-utils
repoquery --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=X -f Y
```

Wildcards are supported for `Y`.

Examples:

```
dnf repoquery --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms -f /usr/bin/zip
dnf repoquery --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms -f /usr/bin/zi*
```

You can also simply `yum provides Y` (or `dnf provides Y`), but this will include installed packages, despite `--disablerepo` switch, on some systems.

### Bonus tip

You can directly install the package requiring a specific filename, by simply passing it to `yum` or `dnf`. Yes, this works and is quite easy:

```
yum install /usr/bin/zip
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder how this is different from running rpm -ql on every package after downloading all the packages (waste of space) and grepping the results, as I tried both methods and I notice that there is a delta between them in some cases, but results are similar.

Comment: There is supposed to be no delta, other than perhaps, ordering of filenames. The `yum` approach will make use of repository metadata. Each repo has so called filelists metadata, which is actually stored in either XML or sqlite database. The `yum` / `dnf` is quering that metadata. But when you use `rpm -ql`, you are quering the package directly. I can't think of a case where metadata vs package data would be having delta other than simply having downloaded packages, and repo was updated with new/changed packages later on.